# Facing error while dropping a materialized view

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am trying to drop a materialized view using the command-

```
DROP  MATERIALIZED VIEW MVIEW_TB_NBN_DAILY
```

Getting error as found in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Somebody was using or refreshing the view at the time? Or something that has a dependency on it perhaps, like a package that references the view directly - perhaps indicating dropping might not be a good idea? Did it persist when you retried it later?

Comment: Thanks for the response.I retried later but no luck:(.

Comment: Did you check the status to see if it was being refreshed?

Comment: You could try a query ([like the one here](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php%3F57696%26p%3D252425%23post252425)) to see what is locking your object; not sure if it's the MV itself that's locked here, or something that is dependant on it which can't be invalidated - maybe check `all_dependencies` to see where the MV is used, and if something using it is locked?

Comment: Maybe you have some deadlock in database - kill sessions which uses view or restart DB.
If you want only refresh view you can use `BEGIN DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH( '"SCHEMA"."MVIEW_TB_NBN_DAILY"','C'); end;`

Comment: A deadlock would be raised as a deadlock error, and could only happen between two sessions that are trying to modify the database.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if another materialized view depends on the one you're trying to drop.

You can check which materialized views reference the one you want to drop (`MVIEW_TB_NBN_DAILY` in your example) using:

```
select *
  from all_dependencies t
 where t.referenced_name = 'MVIEW_TB_NBN_DAILY'
   and t.referenced_type = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'
```

And then drop and recreate the dependent materialized views (and their respective indices, grants, etc.).